# UnityWebRequest security

Tags: unity, security, encryption, http

I have a game where I would like to register users and post the outcome of matches between two users through web requests in Unity but have some security questions regarding `UnityWebRequest`.

Assume the following code for sending a web request:

```
public class TestHTTP : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private bool sendRequest = false;
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (sendRequest)
        {
            Model testModel = new Model();
            testModel.ID = "0001";
            testModel.name = "Random_Name";
            testModel.int1 = 555;
            StartCoroutine(SendWebRequest(testModel));
            sendRequest = false;
        }
    }
    public IEnumerator SendWebRequest(Model m)
    {
        string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(m);
        //string text = JsonUtility.ToJson(SimpleAESEncryption.Encrypt(json, "some_password"));
        using (UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Post($"some_https", json))
        {
            request.method = UnityWebRequest.kHttpVerbPOST;
            request.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            yield return request.SendWebRequest();
            if (request.isNetworkError)
            {
                Debug.Log("NETWORK ERROR:::" + request.error);
            }
            else if (request.isHttpError)
            {
                Debug.Log("HTTP ERROR:::" + request.error);
            }
            else
            {
                string returnData = request.downloadHandler.text;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

After doing a bit of testing I noted that sending via http would give a plain text body, which was remedied by switching to a https target. Is this enough of a level of encryption or should I add a layer of encryption for the model prior to sending?

Lets assume my model contains data regarding the outcome of a match between two players. Would https (TLS 1.2) be enough to stop someone resending the same request/packet to inflate their number of wins for example? Or should additional measures be taken to stop this?

Comment: If you're relying on the client to tell you who won, then all the encryption in the world won't make it secure. Someone could simply decompile the game client, extract the code that forms and sends an "I win" request, and run it in a loop with random variations to frustrate your attempts to spot duplicates. Encryption is good if you're worried about someone spying on the connection and extracting sensitive info like the user's password or contents of their game wallet. It's not the right solution to the threat model of a cheater falsifying their own reports.

Comment: The scenario will be as follows:
1) Match is initiated and assigned an ID after client 1 and client 2 have been matched together
2) Match is played out and both client 1 and 2 would submit the result of the match
3) Both client results would be compared for consistency

Comment: And what problem does double-encrypting the message solve in that scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As DMGregory said in his comment on the question, if you try to prevent cheating on the transport layer, you are doing it wrong. A player who wants to cheat has several opportunities to manipulate their match results *before* they get encrypted by the network system. Encrypting the traffic between game client and server doesn't help much against those. It does not even help against reverse-engineering your network protocol, because the client has all the knowledge it needs to decrypt its own https traffic. Many network analysis tools like Wireshark offer that out-of-the-box.

So this answer focuses on what https is actually meant to prevent: Eavesdropping and packet manipulation by **a 3rd** party (neither the player not your gameserver).

I personally would consider match results to be pretty non-critical here. I doubt that any eavesdropper is interested in those, and there is not much to be gained by changing other people's match results in transit. But what I *would* worry about are passwords for authentication. Users are lazy and tend to use the same password everywhere. They should not, but they still do no matter how often they are told not to. That means that compromising the password for your game could compromise the whole online identity of a player. So passwords should always be considered serious business, no matter the context. And if you already implemented serious transport layer security for passwords, then you can just as well use the same for the gameplay data. It doesn't gain you much, but it doesn't hurt much either.

For most scenarios, https should be good enough. It provides you with encryption which is strong enough to prevent any passive eavesdropping. However, the strength against active eavesdropping through man-in-the-middle (mitm) attack is a different question. It depends on how well Unity validates the server certificate. By default, this depends on the platform. Usually it uses the root certificate store of the operating system. Which means that your server needs a valid certificate signed by a trusted Certificate Authority. Some platforms do not check server-sided certificates at all, which allows a mitm attacker to read and manipulate traffic by replacing the server's certificate with a fake one.

So for maximum security, you might want to use your own [CertificateHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest-certificateHandler.html) and validate it against the public key of your webserver (works on PC, Android and iPhone). Considering that your game is usually only going to communicate with that one server and that you can ship the public key with the game, you have a use-case where a self-signed certificate is actually not a bad idea at all. Getting the certificate authorities out of the picture does not just make things easier, it even improves security in this case because a second certificate by a rogue CA would not get accepted.

An example implementation for a custom certificate handler can be found [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.CertificateHandler.ValidateCertificate.html).

Comment: No critical user data such as passwords will be sent using this setup, only data pertaining to the end of a match. With the certificate additions plus a nonce setup, would this be enough to prevent cheating or should I be looking into the more challenging (in this scenario) solution of taking this logic away from the client?

Comment: @KevinAdams As I wrote in the first paragraph: When you try to prevent cheating on the transport layer, you are doing it wrong. I elaborated a bit on why this is the case.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into cheat prevention prior to data being sent along with a custom certificate handler.
Straight off the bat I can see two assets as improvements:
https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/anti-cheat-toolkit-152334

and

https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/obfuscator-48919

Comment: @KevinAdams I believe you are looking at the wrong mitigations for this problem. Validating the match results on the server is the only way to prevent cheating of this type. Anything client-side can be bypassed by a determined cheater.

Comment: Unfortunately, unless I am mistaken, client side is the only way in which I can add anti-cheat measures if my networking is based on a photon networking system that cannot at this time be replaced.

Comment: @KevinAdams What other methods there are available for preventing cheating is outside of the scope of this question. You might want to post a new one.